# Why doesn't slds card styling show default background?

Tags: lightning-design-system, slds

My code is wrapped in an  and styled with slds-card; not sure why the background is transparent. How can I get the default background styling to show?

[image]

```
    <article className="slds-card">
        <div className="slds-card__header slds-grid">
            <header className="slds-has-flexi-truncate">
                <h2 className="slds-text-heading_small">{! v.filterTitle }</h2>
            </header>
            <span className="slds-badge slds-m-right_small filter-count-badge">{!v.filterCount} </span>
        </div>



        <div className="slds-card__body">

            <div style="margin: 20px">
                <table className="slds-table slds-table_fixed-layout slds-table_bordered slds-no-row-hover slds-table_cell-buffer">
                    <thead>
                        <tr className="slds-text-title_caps">
                            <th>Field</th>
                            <th>Operator</th>
                            <th>Value</th>
                            <th className="slds-cell-shrink" /></tr>
                    </thead>    

                    <tbody>
                        <aura:iteration items="{!v.filterComponents}" var="filterRow">
                            <tr>
                                {!filterRow}
                            </tr>
                        </aura:iteration>
                    </tbody>

                </table>
            </div>

        </div>            


        <footer className="slds-card__footer">
            <lightning:buttonGroup >
              <lightning:button variant="neutral" label="Add Filter" onclick="{!c.addFilter}" />
              <lightning:button variant="neutral" label="Remove Filters" onclick="{!c.removeFilters}" />
              <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Apply and Run" onclick="{!c.fireApplicationEvent}" />
            </lightning:buttonGroup>                



        </footer>            

    </article>
```

UPDATE: I ended up doing the following and it works; issue was using the class attribute instead of classname, but ultimately i just used the standard lightning component.

```
<lightning:card iconName="{!v.filterIcon}"  >
        <aura:set attribute="title">
            <span class="slds-float_left slds-p-left_xx-small slds-p-vertical_xx-small"> {! v.filterTitle }</span>

            <span class="slds-float_right slds-p-right_xx-small slds-p-vertical_xx-small" ><lightning:badge label="{!v.filterCount}" /> </span>

        </aura:set>'
```

Comment: When you edited your post you broke your image. You want want to re-upload it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you're using the wrong attribute `className`. If you want to add the standard lightning design system to your html, you need to use the attribute `class` like this: `<article class="slds-card">`

Is there any reason why you don't use the standard lightning component to insert your card to your component? You should read this [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_card.htm).

Comment: reason i didn't use standard card - was because I couldn't get the title and badge component to align well.. ultimately i ended up doing that though...see my edit